# Use of greatest common divisor to calculate unknown

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

We have three numbers $x ,y, z$. If we know the values of $x$ and $z$ then is it correct to say that $y$ should be a multiple of $z/\gcd(z,x)$ for the expression shown below to be true? Here $\gcd$ means greatest common divisor.

$$(X * Y) \% Z = 0$$

Answer (score 1):

Yes of course.

Let $y=k\frac{z}{\gcd(x,z)}$ and $x=x'\gcd(x,z)$.  Then $$\frac{xy}{z}=\frac{x'\gcd(x,z)\cdot k\frac{z}{\gcd(x,z)}}{z}=x'k$$

Furthermore, if $xy \equiv 0 \mod z$, then $$\frac{xy}{z}=\frac{x'y}{\frac{z}{\gcd(x,z)}}$$

Since $\gcd(x', z/\gcd(x,z))=1$, we know $\frac{z}{\gcd(x,z)}|y$

Answer (score 0):

Yes, $\ z\mid xy \iff  z\mid xy,zy \iff  z\mid (xy,zy)=(x,z)y\iff z/(x,z)\mid y$